# Not a regular if else

Tags: javascript

I want to loop through something, and return true if at any point of loop, condition is met. If not met at all, then want to return false. How do I do this in Javascript.

Cant just write if and else, because only want the else to take care after finish looping all the options...

Comment: Can you show us your attempt with a minimal example?

Comment: So `return true` inside an if condition inside the loop and `return false` after the loop. Or if "something" is an array, look into the `.some()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
if(condition){
   return true;
}

return false;
```

Comment: And this `return !!condition` might work if you really want to return a `boolean`.

Comment: That is definitely another way of doing it @AndrewLi

Comment: How does this help with testing a condition within a loop? @AndrewLi - `return condition` doesn't return a boolean unless `condition` actually is boolean already, so, e.g., `return arr.length` doesn't return a boolean but `return !!arr.length` does.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (x) { */ Do stuff and then eventually */ return true; }
if (y) { */ Do stuff and then eventually */ return true; }
if (z) { */ Do stuff and then eventually */ return true; }
...
return false;
```

If and only if none of the ifs are triggered, it will return false. If any of the ifs are triggered, it will return true within the if

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're saying that you can't use `else` because you want to test *all* conditions, even if multiple of them are true?

If so, then you can use a variable to keep track of your return value, and then just return it at the end:

```
var result = false;
if (condition1) {
    // ... whatever other logic you have ...
    result = true;
}
if (condition2) {
    // ... whatever other logic you have ...
    result = true;
}
// ... etc. ...
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done, return true when the condition is met and return false when the for loop has finished looping. Here is an example :

```
function my_function(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       if (array[i] == 'my_test') {
           return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```